# WordPress - How to get featured post

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm fairly new to WordPress and am trying to build a custom page for blogs. Following the some examples online I have created a custom page template, and also setup a custom post type.

Now I created a page and set it to use new template. I need to add some styles to the featured post and below it have different styling for the rest (total 5 posts).

I can get the posts to show up on the page but how do I separate the featured one so I can style it differently? The post includes a media and some text.

Below is a snippet of the code I'm working with it.

```
<div class="post-box">
    <?php // CUSTOM CODE STARTS: 
   $mypost=array( 'post_type'=> 'story', ); 
   $loop = new WP_Query( $mypost ); ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
    <div <?php post_class( 'post'); ?> id="post-
        <?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="header-top uppercase clearfix"></div>
        <div class="post-home">
            <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_field('name_generator_link'); ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <div class="post-content">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <a class="featured-logo" href="<?php the_field('name_generator_link'); ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full'); ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--blog post-->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); // NAME GENERATOR TOOLS CUSTOM CODE ENDS ?>
</div>
```

Hope I explained my issue well. I really appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: how you marked the post as featured ?

Comment: I created a custom field 'featured' (radio button Yes/No) in the post type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked pretty well for me:

1. Downloaded [Advance Custom Field](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin.
2. Created a field group with one radio button (Yes/No - In the settings I attached it to the 'story' custom post type I created above. We will set this to "yes" for featured posts)
3. On the page template, I used an if/else statement to check if the field is set to yes.
   [image]

We can create/style the elements as needed for featured in the if block and style the rest of post in the else.

Note: To check another post as featured we have to set 'featured' to 'no' on the old featured post.

Hope this helps